# Google Dialog Flow: Change Design/Colours

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I use Google Dialog Flow and I still created a Agent. I want to customize the appeareance of the chat window and I do not know how to do it. It seems like there is no options to do this in the DialogFlow Console. I have seen that there are products like Botcopy, but I want to do it by myself. Do I need to use the API to integrate the bot into my website if I want to change the looks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the DialogFlow web widget is mean to be used for testing, you can hack the CSS and override the way it looks but it is not a recommended approach.

In order to integrate your DialogFlow chatbot on a website you can indeed use Botcopy or Kommunicate (both provide a Widget to add to the web site with some customisation options).

If you are a UI guru you want to build something yourself you can use the DialogFlow SDK https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow